# When I open Java, .jar files are not opened

Tags: java, jar

I have installed the latest version of Jave, but when I run it, the command line screen comes and goes immediately. I am using Windows 10. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What are you running? Some programs don't have interactive user interface but perform action specified with arguments and finish immediately.

Comment: I have a file in .jar format. I installed the Java but when the program does not open. it is UBCG from EZbiocloud

Comment: Okay, and where did you get that .jar from? What is it and how is it supposed to be used?

Comment: https://help.ezbiocloud.net/ubcg-users-manual/

Answer (score 0):

You're running a command line program. It doesn't have a graphical user interface. it accepts arguments through a command line, does what you tell it and exits.

Scroll down [the manual](https://help.ezbiocloud.net/ubcg-users-manual/) to the *Running UBCG pipeline* header and read it.